# PHP MySQL to S3 backup script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I run a nightly cron script on my web server to take a snapshot of all my databases which I then store on S3.

The file I run is on github > [phpMyS3backup](https://github.com/deadlyhifi/phpMyS3backup)

Much of the time it runs fine, however other times I get a `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in ~/phpMyS3backup.php on line 30`.

Which happens in this bit:

```
$GLOBALS['con']= new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
try {
    $res = $GLOBALS['con']->query("SHOW DATABASES");
    while($row = $res->fetch()){
        if($row['Database'] != "information_schema"){
            $alldb[] = $row['Database'];
            deb("Database found: {$row['Database']}");
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of questions:

Why does it fail? If any of the sites are being accessed at the point the script runs, would that stop the script running and cause the error? Like I say, many times it works, other times it does not.

Would it be safe to put the fetch into a loop so that if it does fail it tries again? Or could that end up in an endless loop, or have other performance issues?

Comment: Have you check error_log ?

Comment: I've just had a look and I can't find anything that relates to that script in particular. Is there anything I should looking out for?

Comment: Assuming you're the sysadmin and have root, you really should just use [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/) rather than rolling your own solution.